# ko.computed not working with 2 dimensional observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using following code:

```
self.selectedTags = ko.observable({}); //self is a reference to view model

self.tagsParams = ko.computed(function(){
    var filterParams=self.selectedTags();

    if(Object.keys(filterParams).length>0)
       return $.param(filterParams);

    return null;
}, self);
```

when I push a new item in array,the `tagParams` function doesn't trigger.I am using this:

```
self.selectedTags()[type]=name;
```

Comment: There is no observable array in your sample... and `self.selectedTags()[type]=name; ` is not working by design, because you have directly changed the underlaying object so the KO change tracking is not triggered. You need to something like this: `self.selectedTags()[type]=name;self.selectedTags(self.selectedTags());` but you probably should not use a computed in this scenario anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try doing this -

self.selectedTags()[type]=name; 
self.selectedTags(self.selectedTags());

<s>Or a better approach will be making selectedTags an observable array.</s>

If its a map you can use
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/B7Rzi3DmiS8